# Event source the whole system is bad

Tags: microservices, cqrs, event-sourcing

I'm learning a proper microservice architecture using CQRS, MassTransit and different type of storage for the read side. One thing which often comes along CQRS is the event sourcing. I do understand it's not mandatory at all. However, I can't think of why using it on the whole system is really an anti pattern.

1. Having an store for all events as a single source of truth can help you build / rebuild a read store on the fly whenever you want.
2. You are not locked in to any vendor (except for the event store)

For me, the question is more like is it easier to not start with event sourcing (and still have separate data storage depending on which the microservices. eg: elasticsearch, mongodb, etc etc) and migrating / provisioning whenever it's needed or on the other hand, start with event sourcing everything so that you don't have to deal with migration later on.

Comment: For debate questions like this, the DDD-CQRS-ES slack is the place to go - this is a nuanced thing that'd benefit from a to and fro with different perspectives, i.e. there can be no official Best Practice. That antipattern maxim is a rule of thumb a la the 80/20 rule - event sourcing your core domain has much more bang for buck than anything else.

Answer (score 2):

> I can't think of why using it on the whole system is really an anti pattern.

I agree -- calling it an "anti pattern" is an overstatement.

The spelling I believe?  Using event sourcing on the whole system *isn't cost effective today*.

It could be tomorrow, as we get more practice with it, and the costs of designing these systems goes down and we learn to extract more benefit from them.

In the mean time - how valuable are the temporal queries that you get from event sourcing?  In your core domain, where you get competitive advantage, they could be quite valuable.  In places where you are just doing bookkeeping of information provided to you by the outside world?  Not so much - you may be getting everything you need out of simpler solutions that only keep track of "now".

Comment: I might be too naive here. Instead of thinking about the future, it s more like thinking on what is easier between doing it "right" when starting a project or changing it along the way. For me, it feels easier to do it properly (as in using microservices and cqrs instead of monolith) instead of changing if in the future... When starting a project the scope will be small I believe...

Comment: Having an event history for sure is one of the big advantage of event sourcing. But another one is the fact that you are not dependant on vendors or any type of storage because you can provision any storage from the event store. Eg if you change from dynamodb to cosmosdb, you don't have that much problem...you only have document store for your ecommerce platform and you need graphdb ? Not a problem, you can provision it using your event store. My real worry of the single source of truth is that it s a single point of failure as well as not scalable

Answer (score 0):

I recently published a [blog post](https://dev.to/olibutzki/why-event-sourcing-is-a-microservice-anti-pattern-3mcj) about this issue. It explains why event sourcing is a persistence strategy and shouldn't be used at global scale.

To summarize it: Event Sourcing forces you to emit an event for every changed data. This can result in very fine grained events. If you use Event Sourcing for inter microservice communication, you expose those events to the outside world.

In the end you expose the your persistence layer, comparable to exposing your (relational) database schema in a CRUD based persistence strategy.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying. What I liked about the approach of having a single event store is that... well it's a single source of truth. If I want to build use ElasticSearch and a Nosql store, I just need a new projection. But from my understanding, in your architecture, you would have multiple source of truth? 1 per bounded context? I can see the point though, it's quite a good as well .

Comment: "Search" might be a bounded context which requests some data from other contexts. So one solution is that "Search" specifies what it needs and the bounded context exposes this data.

Comment: Event sourcing does not care about inter-microservice communication.  Domain events and integration events should not be mixed, they should be implemented separately.